# How to get the data like below?

Tags: sql-server

Table is matches

```
TeamA.       TeamB
India.       Srilanka
Pakistan.    India
Australia.   England
Srilanka.    Australia
```

I need a output as below

```
Team.      Numberofmatches
India.          2
Srilanka.       2
Pakistan.       1
Australia.      2
England.        1
```

Comment: Unpivot and `COUNT`, or alternatively `COUNT`, `UNION ALL` and `SUM`.

Comment: `I need a output as below` - what is stopping you from doing that? What have you tried?

Comment: Use UNION ALL for teamA and teamB then country wise count using group by. Why dot(.) after country name in few countries not all..if it really happen then india. and india will give different row...

Answer (score 0):

Just unpivot then aggregate. Unpivoting is easiest done using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  v.team,
  COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (t.TeamA),
    (t.TeamB)
) v(Team)
GROUP BY
  v.team;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/LKVYPnoA)